# Retrieving weights from scales to excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have connected a weighing scale to my PC via an RS-232 to USB converter cable. My goal was to create a command button in excel 2007 that would place the weight from the scale into the selected cell. I got it to work using the following code in a userform.

```
Private Sub XMCommCRC1_OnComm()
    Static sInput As String
    Dim sTerminator As String
    Dim Buffer As Variant

' Branch according to the CommEvent property
    Select Case XMCommCRC1.CommEvent
    Case XMCOMM_EV_RECEIVE
        Buffer = XMCommCRC1.InputData ' Use Input property for MSComm
        sInput = sInput & Buffer
        If Worksheets("Settings").Range("Terminator") = "CR/LF" Then
            sTerminator = vbCrLf
        Else
            sTerminator = vbCr
        End If
        If Right$(sInput, Len(sTerminator)) = sTerminator Then
            XMCommCRC1.PortOpen = False
            sInput = Left$(sInput, Len(sInput) - Len(sTerminator))
            Select Case Left$(sInput, 2)
            Case "ST", "S "
                ActiveCell.Value = CDbl(Mid$(sInput, 7, 8))
                ActiveCell.Activate
            Case "US", "SD"
                MsgBox "The balance is unstable."
            Case "OL", "SI"
                MsgBox "The balance is showing an eror value."
            End Select
            sInput = ""
        End If
    End Select
End Sub


Public Sub RequestBalanceData()
    With Worksheets("Settings")
' Configure and open the COM port
        If Not XMCommCRC1.PortOpen Then
            XMCommCRC1.RThreshold = 1
            XMCommCRC1.RTSEnable = True
            XMCommCRC1.CommPort = .Range("COM_Port")
            XMCommCRC1.Settings = .Range("Baud_Rate") & "," & _
            .Range("Parity") & "," & _
            .Range("Data_Bits") & "," & _
            .Range("Stop_Bits")
            XMCommCRC1.PortOpen = True
        End If

' Send balance's "SI" (Send Immediate) command
' to request weighing data immediately
        If .Range("Terminator") = "CR/LF" Then
            XMCommCRC1.Output = "R" & vbCrLf
        Else
            XMCommCRC1.Output = "R" & vbCr
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

I then created a command button with the following code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    UserForm1.RequestBalanceData

End Sub
```

When I click on the command button the weight is placed in the selected cell. However, this does not consistently happen. Sometimes when I click the button nothing will be placed in the cell, and I will have to click it multiple times until the weight is placed in the cell. I would like to fix this, but I'm not sure where to start. Is it a problem with the code itself, or is it more likely a problem with the converter or the scale itself?

Any help is appreciated.

Here is the scale: https://www.optimascale.com/product-page/op-915-bench-scale

Here is the converter cable: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B06XJZHCV8/ref=ox_sc_act_title_3?smid=A33N7O64F8FSDL&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XJZHCV8)

Here is the tutorial I used for the code: http://www.msc-lims.com/lims/diybalance.html

Here is the ActiveX control from the tutorial that I used: http://www.hardandsoftware.net/xmcomm.htm

EDIT: I have done what Wedge has suggested and placed a Mgsbox sInput after my first End If. I have been getting inconsistent results. I am wondering if I need to change my scales sending format. The scale is currently set to sending format 4.

Here is the scale manual (sending formats are on page 21-23: https://docs.wixstatic.com/ugd/78eff6_e629ae5fe7004c7189060cca4bc7c3de.pdf

2ND EDIT:
I have connected my serial port to putty. My scale is in continuos sending mode. In putty the scale is consistently sending the following: ST,GS+ 0.00lb. However, when i try to enter the weight value in a cell, the message box sometimes displays that part of the data sent (ST,GS+ 0.00lb) has got cut off, or has been sent multiple times with one button press. Does anyone know how I would fix this?

3RD EDIT: It seems to me that the continuous sending mode (mode 4) my scale is set to is sending data too fast and is causing my code to mess up. I would like to try to make this work with the command request mode (mode 3), but I can't figure out how to properly parse the data string and place it into a cell. The sending format for command request mode is :
[image]

If anybody could help me figure out how to get this working I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Probably not the issue here but "sTerminator" is misspelled the second time it's set there. More relevantly put something like "MsgBox sInput" the line after it gets set, and see if it's actually getting a value every time you activate this. The tutorial mentions different scales may have different formats for the data they send and it doesn't seem like you are using either of the models mentioned in the tutorial? So you may need different code to properly parse the data it is sending.

Comment: Set some `Debug.Print "something unique"` inside your code and check what is missing... As no error pops up, it is probably some simple `If` condition which is not true..

Comment: you need to troubleshoot the serial connection first.  download a serial terminal emulator.  this one is very good http://www.putty.org/ .  open a connection to the serial port using the emulator and see if the scale is sending data at a constant rate.